# Powershell test-path against variable contents

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have imported a list of computer names from  csv into a variable.

Now I'd like to test whether a path exists on each computer name from the list

desired output:

```
Computer     Status
--------     ------
computer1    Online
computer2    Offline
```

Below will register the answer as false. That's one answer against 3 machines however.  When i test the `$userscomputer` variable, it does contain the list of `computernames` and some of them are online.

Looks like I'll need to run against each machine in the variable but I've had no success so far. Thanks for reading.

```
$name = "vader"
$usersComputer = import-csv .....etc.
$path = "\\$userscomputer\c$\users\$name"

$componline = test-path $path

$componline
```

The csv file has 2 columns
    "Host Name "        "Logged User"   computer names under host name  and ad names under  Logged user
    computer1         bicard
    computer2         bicard
    computer3         vader

Ideally id like to show which computer is online my thought is below

```
$usersComputer | ForEach-Object {
$cn = $_."Host Name"
$path = "\\$cn\c$\users\$name"
$state = Test-Path $path
write-host $cn, $state

}
```

It outputs below, computer 3 however should report as true ans the $cn  variable is not shown.

failed
failed
failed

I have rejigged your solution this about and it works wonderfully now.  The importing of the CSV file was already done so the variable had the computer names.  There after below worked.

```
$usersComputer | ForEach-Object {
    $cn = $_
        $comp = Test-Path \\$cn\c$\users\$username
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        Computer = $cn
        Status = if ($componline) { 'Online' } else { 'Offline' }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$usersComputer` will contain a collection of objects, and each object will have properties whose names match the columns in the CSV. You haven't provided a sample of what the CSV looks like. So if it has a single column called `ComputerName`, you might do something like this:

```
$usersComputer | ForEach-Object {
    $cn = $_.ComputerName
    $path = "\\$cn\c$\users\$name"
    $componline = Test-Path $path
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Computer = $cn
        Status = if ($componline) { 'Online' } else { 'Offline' }
    }
}
```

Comment: The csv file has 2 columns  1 called logged user and 1 called hostname.   I use below to exract just the hostname     $usersComputer = import-csv C:\Users\bicard\Desktop\csvMergeTest\sheet3.csv |?{$_."Logged User" -eq $name }|%{$_."Host Name"}

Comment: I have edited the original post with my update, Thanks

Comment: That solution worked, I just needed to tweak a couple of things, I have edited the post.   Many thanks